# How to pause on_message for a certain amount of time after it reacts to a message (Discord Py)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a Discord bot that pings a certain user role when an embedded message contains a certain keyword. To avoid ping spam when multiple embedded messages with the keyword are posted, I would like the bot to ping once, then pause for X seconds and then if there's a new message, react to that and then repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you have to import the Time module, then use time.sleep().

import time

time.sleep(x amount of seconds)

Comment: I have tried time.sleep but all it does is wait for X seconds and then react to all messages that were posted in the sleep period.

Comment: can you share the code? does the program react to all the messages at the same time or is there some delay between each one?

Answer (score 0):

`import asyncio` for making the program sleep for mentioned time

in the code :

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
  #do your stuff here
  await asyncio.sleep(10) #10 is time in seconds
  #process after waiting
```